Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54)
While im using the api in localhost. there is no error came in flutter api.
my backend was hosted in my server. after tthat some times the coection is reset.
Unhandled Exception: Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54), address = ***99.com, port = 49834, uri=https://****.com/api/auth/signIn
#0      LoginController.googleSignButton (package:fitish_app/controller/general_controller.dart/login_controller.dart:25:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/profiler_metrics_ios.mm(203)] Error retrieving thread information: (os/kern) invalid argument
flutter: unhandled element <style/>; Picture key: Svg loader
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54), address = ***99.com, port = 54703, uri=https://***.com/api/v1/myClientsProfile
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:154:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:167:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      ApiServices.clientsUnderCoach (package:fitish_app/services/api_services.dart:120:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      CoachHomeController.fetchMyClients (package:fitish_app/controller/coach_controller/coach_home_controller.dart:21:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      CoachHomeController.onInit (package:fitish_app/controller/coach_controller/coach_home_controller.dart:13:5)
<asynchronous suspension>

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: ObxState#dda38):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Obx
  Obx:file:///Users/mohamedrifay/Desktop/Projects/fitish-flutter/lib/screen/coachScreen/coach_home_screen.dart:84:28

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      CoachHomeScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:fitish_app/screen/coachScreen/coach_home_screen.dart:101:67)
#1      Obx.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:72:28)
#2      RxInterface.notifyChildren (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_interface.dart:26:27)
#3      ObxState.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:56:19)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5592:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5480:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5643:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
#8      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:19)
#9      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:989:21)
#10     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:448:5)
#11     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1386:15)
#12     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1311:9)
#13     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1169:5)
#14     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#15     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:399:5)
#16     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)

this is the error i got in my flutter app

either your app or your backend is stopping the connection. please share your code
